# Protractor Custom Locator: Not available in production, but working absolutely fine on localhost

Tags: protractor

I have added a custom locator in protractor, below is the code

```
const customLocaterFunc = function (locater: string, parentElement?: Element, rootSelector?: any) {
  var using = parentElement || (rootSelector && document.querySelector(rootSelector)) || document;
  return using.querySelector("[custom-locater='" + locater + "']");
}

by.addLocator('customLocater', customLocaterFunc);
```

And then, I have configured it inside `protractor.conf.js` file, in `onPrepare` method like this:

```
...
onPrepare() {
    require('./path-to-above-file/');
...
}
...
```

When I run my tests on the localhost, using `browser.get('http://localhost:4200/login')`, the custom locator function works absolutely fine. But when I use `browser.get('http://11.15.10.111/login')`, the same code fails to locate the element.

> Please note, that the test runs, the browser gets open, user input gets provided, the user gets logged-in successfully as well, but the element which is referred via this custom locator is not found.

FYI, 11.15.10.111 is the remote machine (a virtual machine) where the application is deployed. So, in short the custom locator works as expected on localhost, but fails on production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this problem, I used `data-` prefix for the custom attribute in the HTML. Using which I can find that custom attribute on the production build as well.

> This is an HTML5 principle to prepend `data-` for any custom attribute.

Apart from this, another mistake that I was doing, is with the selector's name. In my code, the selector name is in camelCase (loginBtn), but in the production build, it was replaced with loginbtn (all small case), that's why my custom locater was not able to find it on the production build.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but something you'll want to consider.

I remember adding this custom locator, and encounter some problems with it and realised it's just an attribute name... nothing fancy, so I thought it's actually much faster to write

```
let elem = $('[custom-locator="locator"]')
```

which is equivalent to

```
let elem = element(by.css('[custom-locator="locator"]'))
```

than

```
let elem = element(by.customLocator('locator'))
```

And I gave up on this idea. So maybe you'll want to go this way too

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but I think you didn't get my problem completely. I can use your approach only when I have this custom attribute available in the DOM, which in my case, is not being rendered on production. But I see this attribute added in the element on localhost.

Comment: aah.. but then it's not protractor problem, but the app's problem

Comment: I have posted a solution, but your suggestion did come in handy, as the custom protractor locater was not able to find the element. Thank you, I have upvoted.

Comment: Sergey Pleshakiv, just a  small update, I was able to use my custom locater w/o this approach. The mistake that I was doing was with the selector's name. In my code, the selector name is in camelCase (loginBtn), but in the production build, it was replaced with loginbtn (all small case), that's why my custom locater was not able to find it on the production build. Thanks for your help anyway.